# Can i create silverlight pages and use sharepoint data and run silverlight app out off sharepoint?

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint

I need to create silverlight app and connect to sharepoint data to use in silverlight pages and run out of sharepoint.
to this please give me how to connect connect and sample code please.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for ["creating a Silverlight web part in SharePoint"](http://bit.ly/KohOhG) - the first page is full of examples and walkthroughs.